# Cardboard panorama with hotspot

Tags: android, android-studio, google-cardboard

I'm trying to develop a Cardboard application in Android which shows some panoramas. I've studied the api given by google for Cardboard application.
The question is : can I add some hotspot/buttons inside the panorama which are gonna be clickable in order to give the user the possibility to interface with panorama ( info about a single point, or change photo directly on the panorama ). 
I'm starting to think i'm gonna need some renderer for 3D (like Rajawali or OpenGL). 
This is an example : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uxQ9PVne3Ew
This app is build with Unity, but I want something built in native language ( in my case Android ). 
Can you guys suggest me something? 
Thank you in advace

Comment: Can i add some features : like a Webview, or navigate the browser with Android, or adding Unity3D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi everyone : I know there's a lot about this topic so I decided to end this torture.

I'm currently using Rajawali libraries, which is perfect to render 3D objects. 
Follow the instructions, add a sphere or some other object as an hotspot and you'll be fine!

Comment: Any advice on adding hotspots to the sphere?  I'm new to Rajawali and OpenGL myself, so any advice would help.

Comment: hi @bryan, just use a sphere as landscape ( in order to get VR pano ), then add a sphere to the VRSphere, give it a position inside the sphere and use the function `isLookingAtObject()` inside the renderer, and you'll have a hotspot!

Comment: Which version of Rajawali do you use ? On recent version VRActivity is not used in samples. Or do you have a running example ? @sgrumo

Comment: Hi @hannesach. I'm really sorry but that was for a project that's ended 5 years ago. I have no code left since was property of the company I used to work for.